# Eclipse no console output

Tags: eclipse, console

I am facing a funny problem with Eclipse cpp mars on my 32 bit machine with windows 7 installed.

When I run this code, I don't get any console output. But when  I type a number as expected by the code and press enter, it gives me the correct output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x,y;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    if (x<0)
        x = -x;

    if (x <10)
    {
        sum = x;
        printf("\n sum of the digit(s) is: %i",sum);
        return 0;
    }



    for (;x>=10;)
    {
        sum = sum + x%10;
        x = x/10;
    }
    sum = sum + x;

    for (;sum > 9; )
    {
        y = sum%10;
        sum = sum/10;
        sum = sum + y;
    }
    printf("\n sum of the digit(s) is: %i",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I think its an issue with Eclipse, not with my code. Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Is there some sort of output filter enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the documentation of the CDT for eclipse (I ran it in eclipse 3.8).
Your code definitely prints an output ("Enter an integer") and "the sum is", but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. In eclipse, remember to click the build button before running for C programs. Also, make sure the correct compiler is selected and eclipse knows where it is, although you should see an error if this is the case.